# Native javascript promise loop

Tags: javascript, loops, promise

The purpose of this is to loop through a request a few times before proceeding. `github.repos.getBranch` should build an object with 10 elements before I can continue and use the results.

The github api request works as expected, but the results logged at: `console.log('++', res)` come back with the following: `++ [ undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined ]`.
If I log `allBranches` after the loops have finished, the data is all there.

I'm obviously missing a step after the github requests. I have refactored this as many ways as I can think of, with no success.

```
getAllData: () => {
  let allBranches = []
  let startGetData = config.repositories.map(repo => {
    config.branches.map(branch => {
      return allBranches.push(
        github.repos.getBranch({
          owner: config.organisation,
          repo,
          branch
        })
      )
    })
  })

  return Promise.all(startGetData)
  .then(res => {
    console.log('++', res)
  })
}
```

Comment: What end result do you want? I'm guessing an array of repositories, where each entry is an array of branches?

Comment: (Also note that the github API is rate-limited, but I'm guessing either you're not making that many calls, or you've gotten yourself whitelisted.)

Comment: As you say, I want an array of repositories where each is an array of branches. Basically to compare a staging branch against master, to see which is newer. It's a convenience tool, there aren't many requests being made. So far it's just me and i'm the only issue here.

Comment: Okay, I've updated my answer to show one way you'd do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not returning anything from your `config.repositories.map` call (it's a verbose arrow function with no `return`). So you end up with an array of `undefined`, which is what you pass to `Promise.all` You need a `return`.

But that's not the only issue. You're passing `startGetData` into `Promise.all`, but that's not where the github promises are stored. You're storing them in `allBranches`. So you'd need to wait on `allBranches`, not `startGetData`.

I suspect your goal is to get an array of repositories containing an array of branches. If so, you'll need multiple `Promise.all` calls (waiting on the branches of a repository) and an overall `Promise.all` call (waiting for all the repositories to finish).

If that's your goal, here's one way it would look:

```
getAllData: () => Promise.all(                    // Gather up all results
  config.repositories.map(repo =>                 // Map repos to promises
    Promise.all(config.branches.map(branch =>     // Map branches to promises
      github.repos.getBranch({                    // Promise for branch
        owner: config.organisation,
        repo,
        branch
      })
    )).then(branches => ({repo, branches}))       // Wrap up branch results in...
  )                                               // ...an object identifying...
)                                                 // ...the repo
```

That gives you a promise for an array of objects like this:

```
[
    {
        repo: /*...repo...*/,
        branches: [
            /*...branch...*/,
            /*...branch...*/,
            /*...branch...*/
        ]
    },
    {
        repo: /*...repo...*/,
        branches: [
            /*...branch...*/,
            /*...branch...*/,
            /*...branch...*/
        ]
    },
    {
        repo: /*...repo...*/,
        branches: [
            /*...branch...*/,
            /*...branch...*/,
            /*...branch...*/
        ]
    }
]
```

If you just want a pure array of arrays:

```
[
    [
        /*...branch...*/,
        /*...branch...*/,
        /*...branch...*/
    ]
    [
        /*...branch...*/,
        /*...branch...*/,
        /*...branch...*/
    ],
    [
        /*...branch...*/,
        /*...branch...*/,
        /*...branch...*/
    ]
]
```

...then just remove the final `then` clause (`.then(branches => ({repo, branches}))`).

Comment: Thank you! `return Promise.all(allBranches)` gets what I need.

Comment: @TomFirth: Ah, just a simple array. Glad that helped!